# Exporting data from MySQL docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, suppress-warnings

I use the official MySQL docker image, and I am having difficulty exporting data from the instance without errors. I run my export like this:

```
docker run -it --link containername:mysql --rm mysql sh -c 
    'exec mysqldump 
        -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" 
        -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot 
        -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" 
     dbname'
| gz > output.sql.gz
```

However, this results in the warning:

```
"mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure."
```

As the first line of the outputted file. Obviously this later causes problems for any other MySQL processes which are used to consume the data.

Is there any way to suppress this warning from the mysqldump client?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I realise that this is an old question, but for those stumbling across it now I put together a post about exporting and importing from mysql docker containers: https://medium.com/@tomsowerby/mysql-backup-and-restore-in-docker-fcc07137c757
It covers the "Using a password on the command line interface..." warning and how to bypass it.

Answer (score 73):

A little late to answer but this command saved my day.

```
docker exec CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql
```

Comment: beautiful, clean and using docker only

Comment: for me this worked: 

docker exec CONTAINER mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql

Answer (score 8):

**Run Following command on terminal**

```
docker exec CONTAINER_id /usr/bin/mysqldump -uusername --password=yourpassword databasename> backup.sql
```

**Replace the**

1. CONTAINER_id. username, yourpassword

with specific to your configuration.

**To get Container Id :**

```
docker container ls
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I solved this to dump a mysql db into a file.

I created a `dump-db.sh` file with the content:

```
# dump db from docker container
(docker exec -i CONTAINER_ID mysqldump -u DB_USER -pDB_PASS DB_NAME) > FILENAME.sql
```

- To get the CONTAINER_ID list them: `docker container list`

Add run permissions to the script:
`chmod o+x dump-db.sh`

Run it:
`./dump-db.sh`

Remember to replace the CONSTANTS above with your own data.

Answer (score 3):

To eliminate this exact warning you can pass password in `MYSQL_PWD` environment variable or use other connection method - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html

```
docker run -it --link containername:mysql --rm mysql sh -c 
    'export MYSQL_PWD="$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"; exec mysqldump 
        -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" 
        -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot 
     dbname'
| gz > output.sql.gz
```

Comment: How is that accomplished with the official docker image?

Comment: @DanielJames this has little to do with docker itself - you're still dealing with shell scripts, updated answer with example command. Also you can pass env variables from outside with docker's `-e` flag

Answer (score 0):

I always create bash "tools" in my repo root with which I can repeat common tasks, such as database dumps. With bash, you can also load your `.env` file, so your credentials are not in a file in the repo, but just in your .env file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# load .env
set -o allexport; . ./.env; set +o allexport

# setup
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y-%m-%d__%H.%M)
BACKUP_DIR="dockerfiles/db"
CONTAINER_NAME="cp-db"

# dump
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME /usr/bin/mysqldump -u$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME> $BACKUP_DIR/dump__$TIMESTAMP.sql
```